# ATD SIM900 response.?

Tags: sim900

I am designing an application where I am interfacing [SIM900](http://www.zeeman.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ubinetics-at-command-set.pdf) with PIC18F2520. I am making a call to a number using `ATD`. Now if the receiver end do not answer the call, or if its busy, or the call cannot be made. So the current call needs to be diverted to another number. Following are the response of `ATD`

```
OK         Command Executed
ERROR      Invalid Command
BUSY       Receiving end is currently on other call
NO ANSWER  Connection failed upto time out
NO CARRIER Call failed to connect or disconnected
CONNECT    Connection set up(ATX=0)
```

So in my condition, I need to check if the receiver end is `BUSY` or `NO ANSWER` or `NO CARRIER` then make another call.

```
if(
     (strstrrampgm(rxData,(const far rom char *)"NO CARRIER") != NULL) || 
     (strstrrampgm(rxData,(const far rom char *)"BUSY") != NULL) ||
     (strstrrampgm(rxData,(const far rom char *)"NO ANSWER") != NULL)
  )
{
   serialSendString("ATD91xxxxxx78;\r");
}
```

Now whats happening is when I didnt answer the current call `NO ANSWER` or `BUSY` or `NO CARRIER` so the if condition become true it makes another call. But if I accept the first call, GSM does not send `CONNECT` response instead while disconnecting the call it send `NO CARRIER` due to which, the if condition becomes true and second call is made (which is not required). I searched for it and found out the we need to enable `ATX` using `ATX0`, then it shows `CONNECT` response. I tried it but it didn't showed up the `CONNECT`.

Also I want to know that in which cases `NO CARRIER` is received. Whenever there is any network issue, it says `NO CARRIER`. If after connecting the call, we disconnect it, it again shows `NO CARRIER`. If I cut the call, sometimes it shows `BUSY` but sometimes (in another SIM) it shows `NO CARRIER`. What does `NO CARRIER` actually means. What conditions should I check for in my application.
Please help.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Use [original manufacturer site](http://simcomm2m.com/En/) as source of information about what happening and when and why. You can use SIM800 manuals, generally all GSM/GPRS modules are similar. And then try to do all possible variants of AT commands by hand to form your algorithm.

**Second**

There exist `AT+CLCC` command and it's unsolicited response `+CLCC` that can be enabled with command `AT+CLCC=1\r\n`. This response give full information about call state incoming or outgoing and incoming wait calls too. Response format as it described in [SIM800 Series_AT Command Manual_V1.09](http://simcomm2m.com/En/module/detail.aspx?id=74)

```
+CLCC: <id1>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type>,<alphaID>]
```

where:

- `id` is call identification number `1..7`
- `dir` is call cirection `0` - is outgoing, `1` - is incoming
- `stat` is current call state that can be: `active` (connected), `held`, `dialing` (for outgoing call), `alert` (after originated or terminated hangup), `inconimg` (while ring), `wait` (state of incoming call when another call already active), `disconnected` (call end)
- `mode` is voice or data call
- `mpty` is multiparty (conference) call or not

and in addition

- `number`, `type` it is number of mobile terminated and `alphaID` it is related name from phone book if any found.

**Third**

And now you need to implement your own algorithm for maintenance incoming and outgoing calls at the deep what you need. There can be event model and timers and a lot of more.

Anyway you need good parser and modem state monitor algorithm, because in my experience this modem can stop send solicited responses, at any time by some undefined causes. And sometimes only power cycle can help =-).